# Is it possible to remote debug Chrome on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, remote-debugging, ios-webkit-debug-proxy

I am able to successfully debug Safari on iOS 8.4 using Google's [ios-webkit-debug-proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy/). But it never sees my Chrome tabs on the iPad. I've also tried using the desktop Chrome browser at `chrome://inspect` but that also doesn't show it.

Is it possible to remote debug Chrome on iOS? Or is this not possible?

Comment: I don't believe so. You could, however, use firebug bookmarklets to get the developer console

Comment: @Sirens What is "firebug bookmarklets"? Is that an extension for Chrome on iOS?

Comment: Do this http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/02/run-firebug-on-ipad-or-iphone/ just in chrome

Comment: @Sirens it doesn't work

Comment: What "doesn't work"? I use the exact same thing on my iPad. Why do you need chrome for the iPad anyways? It uses a UIWebView anyways

Comment: @Sirens it shows the console but that disappears every time i refresh so it missed all the errors. And I need it because i have to support all the browsers the client wants to use. not my choice

Answer (score 0):

I use Vorlon. http://vorlonjs.com/ It is a free open source project from MS and uses websockets to connect to the remote device. Not as good as full chrome dev tools but you can inspect/edit the dom, view console logs etc.